# How to get rid of the space on the left of a UL?

Tags: html, css

Ok, to explain this I have made a JSFiddle accessible here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qc0ebvmL/)

I would like to remove the spacing on the left of the UL, I have tried removing the list style but this isn't workind. Any help is appreciated.
Thankyou.

```
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding from the list itself, not just the items *within* the list.

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0px;
}
#header {
  background-color: #141414;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #141414;
  width 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
.galleryimg {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img class="galleryimg" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="galleryimg" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="galleryimg" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="galleryimg" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="galleryimg" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></img>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="galleryimg" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="galleryimg" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="galleryimg" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="galleryimg" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="galleryimg" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></img>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  sup m8
</div>
```

Comment: Cant believe I made a mistake like that *sigh*.
Thankyou.